# Wait until method does not throw exception after timeout

Tags: selenium, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm using explicit waits for android app automation with Appium like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(idPrefix + buttonId)));
```

But for some reason after 15 seconds no exception is thrown and the test run is basically still stuck waiting for the element.

The appium logs sometimes print `[base driver] Waiting up to 5000000 ms for condition` but I really have no idea where this number is coming from.

I'm using appium server v1.13.0 with `caps.setCapability(“automationName”, “UiAutomator2");` for android

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you able to step through the code in your debugger? Is it *really* stuck on the call to `wait.until(...)` or is there a line of code after this causing the issue? Can you post more of the code, please?

Comment: Are you using implicit waits? You can't mix implicit and WebDriverWait per the docs... well you can but bad/unexpected stuff sometimes happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT looks like you may have an implicit wait time of 5000 seconds set.

Look for this configuration set somewhere in your code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: No I dont, I actually took out the implicit wait because I read I shouldnt use both.

Comment: That's what the error message "Waiting up to 5000000 ms for condition" indicates to me.

Comment: Did this actually fix your problem? you comment below indicates you searched for 5000 and found the issue?

Comment: Yeah the implicit wait was hidden in some code part with 5000 seconds (I took over a project)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to set “UiAutomator2" capability, it is already the default value for appium 1.13.0.
I took a quick search for such huge timeout value and actually did not find anything.
Do you set implicitlyWait() parameter when you initialize your AndroidDriver? 
It will be very helpful if you provide some part of your code.
If you don't want for the exception to be thrown if there is no element, try using such method to check element for existence:

```
driver.findElementsById(yourId).isEmpty();
```

it will return true or false and there will be no NoSuchElementException which is very conveniently.
NOTE: pay attention of the method name, it is not findElementById(), its findElement**s**ById();

Comment: I WANT a exception to be thrown, my problem is the app is stuck and keeps on searching for the element for ever

Comment: Please provide your code for android driver initialization. I bet you set implicitlyWait timeout and perhaps made a mistake with TimeUnits.

Comment: I only do ```caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");``` I don't set implicit wait only WebDriverWait, but I also tried with ```driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(17, TimeUnit.SECONDS);``` , that also didnt change anything

Comment: have you tried to search "5000" value in your whole project? there is no magic, such huge timeout definitely says that you set it somewhere in your code.

Comment: Oh my god thanks, for some reason I only searched for 'driver.manage().timeouts()'